# Why can't I walk?

Tags: goat-simulator

When I play goat simulator, sometimes it doesn't let me walk, can ANYONE explain why does it happen please?
I already tried exiting the game three time and restarting/re-spawning.

Comment: I can't... but... you can be a goat !

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: seems pretty clear to me..

Comment: @Timelord64 Unclear is often used because the user needs to provide additional details before we can help.  In that sense, this is rather unclear.

Comment: @Frank, maybe, if you choose to ignore the english defenition of the word. Alternativley, if you think the question needs more details for a more localised answer, you are describing the definition of "too broad". On that side, I still disagree.

Comment: @Timelord64 "Hey, we need more details in order to be able to help you."  The details that have been provided are insufficient.  That's a pretty good use case for Unclear.